# Split txt file into smaller ones but keep header

Tags: python

I have the following piece of code which I use to split a .txt file into smaller files. I would like to keep the headers (first three rows of the file) in each small file that gets created by the script.

```
 smallfile = None
                with codecs.open(sourcePath + '/' + file, 'r','latin-1') as bigfile:
                    for lineno, line in enumerate(bigfile):
                        if lineno % lines_per_file == 0:
                            if smallfile:
                                smallfile.close()
                            small_filename = sourcePath + '/_' + file.replace(".txt", "") + '_{}.txt'.format(lineno + lines_per_file)
                            smallfile = codecs.open(small_filename, 'w', 'latin-1')
                        smallfile.write(line)
                    if smallfile:
                        smallfile.close()
```

Any help on how to do so would be highly appreciated.

Comment: What's the *problem* with what you've posted?

Comment: @jonrsharpe, it does split the file into smaller chunks, but without headers. In the big file, the first three lines are headers, and I would like to add those three lines to all the smaller files.

Comment: So have you tried to write any code to do that? There's no evidence of it in what you've posted.

Comment: @jonrsharpe, there are examples online on how to do this using pandas, but I cannot find any suggestion for the approach I am using.

Comment: This isn't always going to be copypasta - have you tried to actually write anything? If not, go and do that.

Answer (score 1):

Collect the first three lines you read from `bigfile` into a list and then print this list whenever you open a new `smallfile`.